# JSON field Desrializing to lowercase in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a `Spring Boot Controller` -

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

   @PostMapping
   @ResponseStatus(CREATED)
   public UserResponse register( @Valid @RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {
     //return ....
   } 
}
```

Below is UserRequest.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class UserRequest {

    private String email;
    //other property
}
```

I am sending below json in request body -

```
 {
   "email" : "TEST@Example.com",
   //some other fields.
 }
```

Sometime client send `email` in uppercase or in camel case so in `userRquest` I want to change value of `email` field to lowercase like `test@example.com` while de serializing to `UserRequest` Object.

Is there any easy way to do this. Can I introduce my own `annotation` like `@ToLowerCase` how I can create my own annotation and use that at field level in `UserRequest`.

Comment: Question is bit confusing, can you add UserRequest class and sample json that you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 6):

There is no easy way just by introducing a new annotation `@ToLowerCase`,
because then you would also need to implement some annotation processor
for doing the real conversion work.

But you can achieve your goal in a slightly different way.
In your `UserRequest` class annotate the `email` property
with [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) and specify a [`converter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html#converter()) there.

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter = ToLowerCaseConverter.class)
private String email;
```

You need to implement the converter class by yourself,
but it is easy by extending it from [`StdConverter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/StdConverter.html).

```
public class ToLowerCaseConverter extends StdConverter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(String value) {
        return value.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Jackson will use the setter methods in your class.
Perform the conversion to lower case in the setter.

For example

```
public void setEmail(final String newValue)
{
    email = StringUtils.lowerCase(newValue);
}
```

`StringUtils` is an apache commons class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a general `StringDeserializer` and register it in `ObjectMapper` as shown below:-

**StringDeserializer class**

```java
public final class StringDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {

    public StringDeserializer() {
        super((Class<String>) null);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        JsonToken token = parser.getCurrentToken();

        if (token == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            String text = parser.getText();
            return text == null ? null : text.toLowerCase().trim();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**JacksonConfiguration class**

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    void mapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper.registerModule(initModule());
    }

    private Module initModule() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(String.class, new StringDeserializer());
        return module;
    }
}
```

The above code makes jackson deserialize all strings to lowercase and trimmed.